# DirectX - dimension of vertices passed to the vertex shader

Tags: directx

I'm tryingto learn directX programming. Looking at different tutorials there is something about Vertices that i find a bit counfusing.

I know that directX uses vertices with four elements (x,y,z,w). I saw many tutorials ( example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff729721(v=VS.85).aspx ) passing XMFLOAT3 as vertices positions omitting the w component. How this works ? Assuming that passin XMFLOAT3 or XMFLOAT4 doesn't change DirectX behaviour (true? ) should i set the w to 1 in the vertex shader or DirectX assumes it to be 1 by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The memory format of vertices is described by the Input Layout. To save space, one usually provides position as a 3-vector rather than a 4-vector with .w always set to 1.

```
D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC[] =
{
    { "SV_Position", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT,    0, D3D11_APPEND_ALIGNED_ELEMENT, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
...
};
```

Any element not specified by the input layout is usually assumed to be 0, but in HLSL the macros for things like `mul(float3,float4x4)` already know to make the .w an implicit 1.

You should take a look at VertexTypes.h in the [DirectX Tool Kit](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248929) for various examples.